# navigation problem in action script 3.0 kindly help in this

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 2 movie clips (abc) and (xyz) I'm in the "1st" frame in the timeline and I kept abc movie clip. In that, there are 3 frames and I kept another movie clip (xyz) in the 45th frame in main timeline. my question is how to navigate from the 3rd frame of (abc) movie clip to the main timeline's 45th frame movie clip(xyz)'s frame"2"?

```
MovieClip(parent).xyz.gotoAndStop(2);
```

Comment: While you are on frame 1 of main timeline, there is no `xyz` MC on the stage, and you plain cannot navigate it. You need some logic in `xyz` MC that would check if it was instructed to display a certain frame at time when it can react to `addedToStage` event.

Comment: Okay, what frame is your main timeline at? If not 45, there might (most likely) be no `xyz` MC available.

Comment: I have 2 movieclips in time line named as a1 and a2. each movie clip has 10 frames. a1 is in 1st frame and a2 is in 2nd frame. I have a button on 1st frame which leads to 2nd frame. in second frame a2 movie clip will be played and at the last frame of a2 movie clip, i want to jump in to a1 movie clip frame 5. is there any solution for it. kindly help us

Comment: Is this solved now or you still need help with it?